# How to use MediaSessianCompat for Media playback?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have spent literally a whole day trying to understand how MediaSessionCompat works and what exactly it does? How is it different from MediaPlayer or AudioManager class? But to be honest I did not find any good explanation. The only info I got was from the android docs and some codes I found on the web which, according to me are not sufficient in this case. The only helpful thing was [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBC1FgWe5X4&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc-lJo_RGGXL2Psr8vVCTWjM&index=4) video by Ian Lake that I found on Youtube. But I am still not able to understand how can we use it in our app.

This is another code I found by Ian Lake, and I spent quite some time on it but still I have lots of doubts.

```
package com.example.remotecontrolclient;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat;

public class PlayerService extends Service {
    private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), RemoteReceiver.class.getName());
        mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "PlayerService", receiver, null);
        mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
        mediaSession.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED, 0, 0)
                .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)
                .build());
        mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "Test Artist")
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, "Test Album")
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "Test Track Name")
                .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, 10000)
                .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART,
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .build());

        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.requestAudioFocus(new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                // Ignore
            }
        }, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        mediaSession.setActive(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (mediaSession.getController().getPlaybackState().getState() == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING) {
            mediaSession.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                    .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED, 0, 0.0f)
                    .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE).build());
        } else {
            mediaSession.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                    .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 1.0f)
                    .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE).build());
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaSession.release();
    }
}
```

Can someone please provide a link to some tutorial or blog that explains what MediaSessionCompat is and how it is used for Media Playback. If not can someone provide a simple example to play, pause and stop any media say, an mp3 filefrom an activity using MediaSessionCompat. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

You can watch

- [Media playback the right way - BBQ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQwe30cZffg) and Android Dev Submit
- [State of media playback](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6pFai3ll9E)